# Cutting an Image into pieces through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a simple Jigsaw puzzle. In order to do this, I need to cut the picture I am using into 20 pieces. Is there a way in Javascript to cut a picture into 20 equal pieces and save them as 20 different objects within the webpage? Or do I just have to go into photoshop and cut each picture out myself and call it in?

Comment: A canvas element would let you "cut out" pieces, but exactly how to do it would depend on your exact requirements around what you want to *do* with the pieces.

Comment: I want the pieces to be able to be draggable and droppable. I am currently using Jquery for this task, but as this feature is not supported, and the third party add-ons aren't working, I am shirking away from using Jquery. I might change over to HTML5 if it can drag and drop. Anyways,  I basically want  20 different images that I can drag and drop onto a frame so they can "solve" the puzzle.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this by setting the image as a background on a div, then setting its background-position. This is basically the same as using [CSS Sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).

(assume pieces are 100 x 100px)

```
<div class="puzzle piece1"></div>
<div class="puzzle piece2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.puzzle {
   background-image:url(/images/puzzle.jpg);
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
}

.piece1 {
   background-position:0 0
}

.piece2 {
   background-position:-100px -100px
}
```

Answer (score 34):

This is easy to do with Canvas. The general idea is:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = cutImageUp;
image.src = 'myimage.png';

function cutImageUp() {
    var imagePieces = [];
    for(var x = 0; x < numColsToCut; ++x) {
        for(var y = 0; y < numRowsToCut; ++y) {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = widthOfOnePiece;
            canvas.height = heightOfOnePiece;
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(image, x * widthOfOnePiece, y * heightOfOnePiece, widthOfOnePiece, heightOfOnePiece, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            imagePieces.push(canvas.toDataURL());
        }
    }

    // imagePieces now contains data urls of all the pieces of the image

    // load one piece onto the page
    var anImageElement = document.getElementById('myImageElementInTheDom');
    anImageElement.src = imagePieces[0];
}
```

Comment: This might give SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Comment: @MertKoksal 

Its because of CORS 
You can set:
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
refer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20424457/7121889

Answer (score 1):

you can use the drawImage method to slice parts of a source image and draw them to a canvas:

```
drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

something like :

```
  document.getElementById("vangogh").onclick=function()
    {
    draw();
    }; 

 function draw() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('source'),33,45);
                 }
```

then create draggable content for your new entities :

```
<div id="columns">
   <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>A</header></div>
   <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>B</header></div>
   <div class="column" draggable="true"><header>C</header></div>
</div>
```

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break an image into separate pieces, you could create elements with the same background image URL and give them different background coordinates.

```js
initializeAllPuzzles();

document.querySelector('button[data-action="shuffle"]')
  .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    shuffleChildren(document.querySelector('.puzzle'));
  });

function initializeAllPuzzles() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.puzzle').forEach(initializePuzzle);
}

function initializePuzzle(puzzle) {
  const options = {
    imgSrc: puzzle.dataset.src,
    width:  +puzzle.dataset.width,
    height: +puzzle.dataset.height,
    size:   +puzzle.dataset.size
  };
  const columns = options.width / options.size;
  Object.assign(puzzle.style, {
    display: 'grid',
    gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${columns}, 1fr)`,
    
  });
  for (let y = 0; y < options.height; y += options.size) {
    for (let x = 0; x < options.width; x += options.size) {
      puzzle.append(createPiece(x, y, options));
    }
  }
}

function createPiece(x, y, options) {
  const piece = document.createElement('div');
  Object.assign(piece.style, {
    width: `${options.size}px`,
    height: `${options.size}px`,
    background: `url(${options.imgSrc}) -${x}px -${y}px`
  });
  return piece;
}

function shuffleChildren(el) {
  const tmp = el.cloneNode(true);
  for (let i = tmp.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    tmp.appendChild(tmp.children[Math.random() * i |0]);
  }
  el.parentNode.replaceChild(tmp, el);
}
```

```css
.puzzle {
  gap: 0.125rem;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-action="shuffle">Shuffle</button>
<div
  class="puzzle"
  data-src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Ayj.jpg"
  data-width="1500"
  data-height="1500"
  data-size="60"></div>
```