# canvas.toDataURL() SecurityError

Tags: javascript, canvas, cors

So I'm using google maps and I get the picture so it looks like this

```
<img id="staticMap"
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false">
```

I need to save it. I have found this:

```
function getBase64FromImageUrl(URL) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = URL;
    img.onload = function() {

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        alert(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));

    };
}
```

But I get this problem:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': tainted canvases may not be exported.

I searched for fixes. I found a sample here [How to use CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server) but still I can't tie these 2 pieces of code together to make it work. Maybe I'm doing it the wrong way and there is a simpler way to do it? I'm trying to save this pic so that I can transfer the data to my server. So maybe someone did something like this and knows how to make `.toDataURL()` work as I need it?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Unless google serves this image with the correct `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, then you wont be able to use their image in canvas. This is due to not having `CORS` approval. You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image), but it essentially means:

> Although you can use images without CORS approval in your canvas,
>   doing so taints the canvas. Once a canvas has been tainted, you can no
>   longer pull data back out of the canvas. For example, you can no
>   longer use the canvas toBlob(), toDataURL(), or getImageData()
>   methods; doing so will throw a security error.
>
> This protects users from having private data exposed by using images
>   to pull information from remote web sites without permission.

I suggest just passing the URL to your server-side language and using curl to download the image. Be careful to sanitise this though!

**EDIT:**

As this answer is still the accepted answer, you should check out [@shadyshrif's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27260385/475125), which is to use:

```
var img = new Image();
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
img.src = url;
```

This will **only** work if you have the correct permissions, but will at least allow you to do what you want.

Comment: I'd take the remote alternative suggestion from @Prisoner further  and propose making it the default behaviour. The server will almost certainly be able to receive the _img.src_ then *wget*/*cURL* the image quicker than the client could encode a local-origin image and POST it to the server. Perhaps, only if client-side authentication is required (i.e. your server's attempt ends with a `403`), you could fall-back to using `canvas.toDataURL(img)` in the hopes that it's being served from the same origin as the page. This default behaviour will also result in the original file (EXIF et al.)

Comment: I have set my Google Cloud Storage bucket to "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" yet I still get this security error when trying to use the toDataURL() method. The image is being served to the Canvas via the URL generated from "getImageServingUrl"

Comment: TIL: It is crucial to set the `crossOrigin` attribute before setting `img.src`.

Comment: It doesn't work because, in my case, the server is not sending the CORS headers. Without the crossOrigin attribute I can load the images but using it I can't

Answer (score 62):

Just use the [`crossOrigin` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Attributes) and pass `'anonymous'` as the second parameter

```
var img = new Image();
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
img.src = url;
```

Comment: To clarify, this will not work for servers that directly wont let the resource to you. That mean, that this will work only for public resources, or missconfigured servers.

Comment: I've also had to add a timestamp to the image URL to avoid the storage server from responding with 304 without the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Like this `img.src = url + '?' + new Date().getTime();`

Comment: didn't work for me in IE11 with images the use data-url source

Answer (score 6):

This method will prevent you from getting an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error from the server you are accessing to.

```
var img = new Image();
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
img.src = url + '?' + timestamp;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the code below ...

```
<img crossOrigin="anonymous"
     id="imgpicture" 
     fall-back="images/penang realty,Apartment,house,condominium,terrace house,semi d,detached,
                bungalow,high end luxury properties,landed properties,gated guarded house.png" 
     ng-src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" 
     height="220"
     width="200"
     class="watermark">
```

Comment: what is the reason of pointless value of `fall-back` attribute?

Comment: I believe the only reason this works is because of `crossOrigin="anonymous"` the rest is irrelevant. I'm also pretty sure `ng-src` is not native javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using the WebBrowser control (forcing IE 11) and I could not get past the error. Switching to CefSharp which uses Chrome solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. I had the file in a simple .html, when I passed the file to php in Apache it worked

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector('#toPrint')).then(canvas => {
            let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
            pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0, 0, 211, 298);
            pdf.save(filename);
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

if the picture from the 3rd party site didn't set the header for cors ("access-control-allow-origin"), you can never download the picture file through chrome,
even if you use the setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
Here are some suggestions

1. hack chrome (use an extension, this will only work on your machine)
2. proxy the image through a service running on your site. The browser will see the domain as your site. This requires your service to request the image from the 3rd party.

Answer (score -3):

By using [fabric js](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1#canvas) we can solve this security error issue in IE.

```
    function getBase64FromImageUrl(URL) {
        var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            var canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas1.width = this.width;
            canvas1.height = this.height;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: "png"});
        };
        img.src = URL;
    }
```