# How to save image from canvas with CSS filters

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I need to save an image after using CSS filters on the client-side (**without** using a backend). What I have so far:

1. Use CSS filters
2. Convert to canvas
3. Save with `var data = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");`
4. Crying. Image was saved without effects.

### Index.html

```
<div class="large-7 left">
    <img id="image1" src="./img/lusy-portret-ochki-makiyazh.jpg"/><br>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

### Photo.js

```
var buttonSave = function() {
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var img = document.getElementById('image1');
    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext ? myCanvas.getContext('2d') : null; 
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
        var grayValue = localStorage.getItem('grayValue');
        var blurValue = localStorage.getItem('blurValue');
        var brightnessValue = localStorage.getItem('brightnessValue');
        var saturateValue = localStorage.getItem('saturateValue');
        var contrastValue = localStorage.getItem('contrastValue');
        var sepiaValue = localStorage.getItem('sepiaValue');

        filterVal = "grayscale("+ grayValue +"%)" + " " + "blur("+ blurValue +"px)" + " " + "brightness("+brightnessValue+"%)" + " " + "saturate(" + saturateValue +"%)" + " " + "contrast(" + contrastValue + "%)" + " " + "sepia(" + sepiaValue + "%)" ;
        $('#myCanvas')
          .css('filter',filterVal)
          .css('webkitFilter',filterVal)
          .css('mozFilter',filterVal)
          .css('oFilter',filterVal)
          .css('msFilter',filterVal);

    var data = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    localStorage.setItem("elephant", data);
    if (!window.open(data)) {
        document.location.href = data;
    }

}
```

However, this produces an image without any filters.

Answer (score 11):

There is a little known [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) on the context object, conveniently named `filter`.

This can take a CSS filter as argument and apply it to the bitmap. <del>However, this is *not* part of the official standard and it only works in Firefox so there is the limitation.</del>. This has since this answer was originally written become a part of the [official standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#filters).

You can check for the existence of this property and use CSS filters if it does, or use a fallback to manually apply the filters to the image if not. The only advantage is really performance when available.

CSS and DOM is a separate world from the bitmaps that are used for images and canvas. The bitmaps themselves are not affected by CSS, only the elements which acts as a looking-glass to the bitmap. The only way is to work with at pixel levels (when *context*'s filter property is not available).

How to calculate the various filters can be found in the [Filter Effects Module Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#ShorthandEquivalents). Also see [SVG Filters](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html) and [Color Matrix](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#feColorMatrixElement).

## Example

This will apply a filter on the context it self. If the filter property does not exist a fallback must be supplied (not shown here). It then extracts the image with applied filter as an image (version to the right). The filter must be set *before* next draw operation.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = ""; 
img.onload = draw; img.src = "//i.imgur.com/WblO1jx.jpg";

function  draw() {
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.width = this.width;
  canvas.height = this.height;
  
  // filter
  if (typeof ctx.filter !== "undefined") {
    ctx.filter = "sepia(0.8)";
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  }
  else {
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    // TODO: manually apply filter here.
  }

  document.querySelector("img").src = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

```css
canvas, img {width:300px;height:auto}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas><img>
```

Comment: The property is now [part of a standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#filters) and is supported in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Please note that you have to `drawImage` in order to get the filters to apply on the image data. If you use `putImageData` on the other hand, you are manually settings the pixels, so filter will not apply. You can however get image bitmap from image data in order to draw on the target canvas, or, use another canvas where you put the image data - that can be then drawn on the target one.

Answer (score 3):

CSS filters applied to the canvas will not be applied to the image that is produced. You either need to replicate the filters in canvas or rather re apply the same filters to the generated image.

Try putting the generated image data into the source of an img tag & apply the same filters.

Comment: Wdym? Please clarify with an example

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS properties are not actually applied to the canvas data. Think of the CSS as being another layer placed over the canvas element. You can implement your own image filters by using `context.getImageData` to get an array of raw RGBA values, then do your filter work and then write it back with `context.putImageData`. However, I think you really just want to save the output of the CSS filters. You may be able to do this using a tool like [rasterizeHTML](http://cburgmer.github.io/rasterizeHTML.js/)

Answer (score 1):

Note, if `src` of `img` is not located at same origin calling `var data = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png")` , may cause `error`

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

Note also that image at `html` at Question appear to be type `jpg` , not `png`

```
<img id="image1" src="./img/lusy-portret-ochki-makiyazh.jpg"/>
```

A possible "workaround" could be to set `img` `src` as a `data URI` of image ; calling

```
var data = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpg")
```

Though as noted , at Answers above , would not appear to preserve `css` `filter` set at `img` element.

---

Note, "workaround" ; "save image" here , would be "save html" ; as the "download" would be an `objectURL` of the `DOM` `html` `img` element.

Note also , `img` `src` within saved `html` file will still be original local or external `src` of image ; if not converted to `data URI` before loading.

Approach is to set `window.location.href` as an `objectURL` reference to `DOM` `img` element `outerHTML` , which should preserve `style` attribute set at  `.css("[vendorPrefix]-filter", filterVal)`

Try utilizing `URL.createObjectURL` , `URL.revokeObjectURL` ; setting `css` `filter` at `img` , instead of `canvas` element ; creating `Blob` of `img` `outerHTML` , `type`:`text/html` ; create reference to `URL.createObjectURL`: `objURL` ; set `window.location.href` to `objURL` ;
call `URL.revokeObjectURL` on `objectURL` reference `objURL`

```js
var buttonSave = function() {
  var img = document.getElementById("image1");
  // filters
  var grayValue = "0.2";
  var blurValue = "1px";
  var brightnessValue = "150%";
  var saturateValue = "0.2";
  var contrastValue = "0.2";
  var sepiaValue = "0.2";
  // `filterVal`
  var filterVal = "grayscale(" + grayValue + ") "
                  + "blur(" + blurValue + ") "
                  + "brightness(" + brightnessValue + ") "
                  + "saturate(" + saturateValue + ") "
                  + "contrast(" + contrastValue + ") "
                  + "sepia(" + sepiaValue + ")";
  // set `img` `filter` to `filterVal`
  $(img)
  .css({
    "webkit-filter": filterVal,
    "moz-filter": filterVal,
    "ms-filter": filterVal,
    "o-filter": filterVal
  });
  // create `blob` of `img` `outerHTML` ,
  // `type`:`text/html`
  var blob = new Blob([img.outerHTML], {
    "type": "text/html"
  });
  // create `objectURL` of `blob`
  var objURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  console.log(objURL);
  // download `filtered` `img` as `html`
  var download = $("<a />", {
    "download": "image-" + $.now(),
    "href": objURL,
    // notify file is type `html` , not image
    "title":"click to download image as `html` file"
  }).appendTo("body");
  $(img).appendTo("a");
    
  $("a").on("click", function() {
    // set `location.href` to `objURL`
    window.location.href = objURL;
    $(window).one("focus", function() { 
      // revoke `objURL` when `window` regains `focus`
      // after "Save as" dialog
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objURL);
    });
  });
  
}

window.onload = buttonSave;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="large-7 left">
  <img id="image1" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed response. Yes image in .html file with filters but when saving on computer this image not contains filters(

Comment: @ЕвгенийУсов Tried setting src of initial image as data URI , instead of url ? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066354/image-effects-to-canvas-image-not-save-with-php-upload-but-applies-to-download-o , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975138/how-can-i-get-pngbase64-with-images-inside-of-svg-in-google-charts/