# CSSGram / CSS filter & Blend mode - how to export

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, css-filters

I use the CSSGram library to apply some CSS filters to my images, like this :

```
<figure class="aden">
  <img src="../img.png">
</figure>
```

The problem is that I have to send the image with the applied filter to my server. I have try with Javascript & the canvas, but without success !
Unfortunately, I can't find any solution that works on all browsers and even on mobile!

I'm searching for a solution, but can't find a method that works with CSS filter & blend mode (and not Canvas filter, which is a different beast).

Any idea?

Comment: The only way to do this is by using `<canvas>` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30408939/how-to-save-image-from-canvas-with-css-filters

Comment: Thanks @TedWhitehead , but the ctx.filter is not a CSS filter & blend ! So I have to build a corresponding filter...

Answer (score -1):

You can do some things much more better. The usuage of js lets you preload in the hidden. The base may be set to invisible first. The CSS could be optimized to oldschool. The problem you are reporting between the lines isnt a new one. Different browsers were made by different nerds. A standard maybe accomplished, if these age of scriptkidding has been passed.

I'll suggest a CSS3 style, the js to preload onload and the z-index makes you happy.