# HTML5 video screenshot via canvas using CORS

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas

I have an issue getting screenshots of videos in Chrome, and I've exhausted all the internets and all Stackoverflow answers on it; no luck.

No matter what I try, when I try to use the `canvas` element to take a screenshot of a video that is on a different domain, or even just a different port, then I end up with a `Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.` error.

Here is my setup:

**Web app URL**
http://client.myapp.com/home.html

**CDN URLs (I've tried both)**
http://client.myapp.com:8181/somevideo.mp4
http://cdn.myapp.com/somevideo.mp4

Headers sent back with MP4 from CDN:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:x-ms-request-id,Server,x-ms-version,Content-Type,Last-Modified,ETag,x-ms-lease-status,x-ms-lease-state,x-ms-blob-type,Accept-Ranges,Content-Length,Date,Transfer-Encoding
Content-Length:5253832
Content-Range:bytes 48-5253879/5253880
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Sat, 06 Feb 2016 17:24:05 GMT
ETag:"0x8D32E3EDB17EC00"
Last-Modified:Fri, 05 Feb 2016 15:13:08 GMT
Server:Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-lease-state:available
x-ms-lease-status:unlocked
x-ms-request-id:88d3aaef-0629-4316-995f-021aa0153c32
x-ms-version:2015-04-05
```

I have:

- Added `crossOrigin="anonymous"` to the video element, but this just makes the video fail to load altogether
- Tried even the same domain on a different port (as above)
- Ensured that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is coming back with `*` (as above)
- I don't believe it is DRM as the screenshot works fine if I copy the exact same video file to the web app and load it locally
- Run through all answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424279/canvas-todataurl-securityerror), but this is for images not videos anyway and the answers only describe all the previous points

Yet, still the blasted error.

**Edit**
Added code:

```
var getScreenshotDataUrl = function(video, canvas, type) {
    type = type || "image/jpeg";
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var w = video.videoWidth;
    var h = video.videoHeight;
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
    video.crossorigin = "anonymous";// makes no difference
    return canvas.toDataURL(type);
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you please post your code here not a link here.

Comment: Try looking at this resource https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: @Binvention I've added the code. It works non-CORS.

Comment: What about the env=IS_CORS in the header for the picture?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have answered my own question.

What a horrible headache I now have.

The problem lies somewhere in the nuanced specification of the HTML5 video crossorigin/CORS specification.

I only tested in Chrome and Edge, but here is what you need to know at the time of writing:

## Chrome

Loading your HTML5 video will fail *if* you have `crossOrigin` set, but your video is being served from any port other than *80* ***and*** is **not** using `https`:

**THIS WILL FAIL**
Client at http://www.myapp.com/player.html:

```
<video crossOrigin="anonymous" src="http://cdn.myapp.com:81/video.mp4"></video>
```

**THIS WILL SUCCEED**
Client at http://www.myapp.com/player.html:

```
<video crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.myapp.com:81/video.mp4"></video>
```

## Chrome and Edge

`getImageData()` and `toDataURL()` will be security blocked *unless*:

- **crossorigin** is set to `anonymous` or `use-credentials` ([as defined here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes)) **before** the video is loaded. If you do this too late, it will still fail.

## All

Finally, if you are going to set `crossOrigin` in javascript, be sure to use the correct casing for the javascript property: `crossOrigin` (NOT `crossorigin`)

[I have written this up in a little more detail in my blog](http://overengineer.net/enabling-cors-for-html5-video-element-screenshots).

Comment: Thank you. I had the same experience and couldn't find much in the way of documentation/answers online. Guess/test/revise for a day and a half yielded little as well.  This post got it resolved for me. Thanks so much