# Export Canvas to Image(using toDataUrl) in shopify using fabric js

Tags: javascript, canvas, shopify, fabricjs

I am working on a shopify app that will be used to customize the products, I am using fabric.js to manipulate different canvas objects and at the end, what I want is to export the customized image from the canvas.

But the issue that I'm facing is that when I use **canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")**, it gives me this error:

> SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

I'm looking for some help regarding this, any sort of helpful input is appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty clear you're running into a security problem. Without you explaining more on your setup, its all a guess but it took 2 seconds to find this: [canvas.toDataURL() SecurityError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424279/canvas-todataurl-securityerror)