# How to get image data from src attribute?

Tags: jquery, image

Hi I am trying to get the image data from img tag using jquery.

```
var imagedata = $('.avatar_store img').attr('src');
```

I am getting undefined as return to this imagedata.How to read this image as blob in base64 format.Can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: add ur tag with this class avatar_store img

Comment: Are you sure you get elements matches your selector? check `$('.avatar_store img').length`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [canvas.toDataURL() SecurityError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424279/canvas-todataurl-securityerror)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<img id="imageid" src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}

var base64 = getBase64Image(document.getElementById("imageid"));
```

**Source**

[CONVERT Image url to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172604/convert-image-url-to-base64)

Comment: It's good if you add some explanation or better past the Link where you copied the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172604/convert-image-url-to-base64/#answer-22172860

Comment: Apologies @Satindersingh. Will keep in mind from next time.

Comment: So this seems to work but the browser gives me a security error about tainted canvases. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @Rozgony instead of `document.createElement("canvas");` make it `document.getElementById('myCanvas');`  That should remove the security based error

Answer (score 0):

You can get image data using canvas:

```
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        dataURL;

    canvas.height = this.height;
    canvas.width = this.width;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
    console.log('base64', dataURL);

    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
        console.log('blob', blob);
    });
};
img.src = $('.avatar_store img').attr('src');
```