# Tainted canvases

Tags: canvas, printing, openlayers-3, mapserver

I'm using openlayers 3 to draw some areas of interest (Vector layer) on Bing maps. The application may also create a table with data drawn on OL3 cavnas.
Then the user may send to printer the created map with the following code.

```
function handlePrintMap() {
  var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
  var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');  

  var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
  windowContent += '<html>'
  windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
  windowContent += '<body>'
  windowContent += '<img src="' + dataUrl + '">';
  windowContent += '</body>';
  windowContent += '</html>';
  var printWin = window.open('','','width=1280,height=1027');
  printWin.document.open();
  printWin.document.write(windowContent);
  printWin.document.close();
  printWin.focus();
  printWin.print();
  printWin.close();
}
```

Till this point everything works as planned.

Another layer is added, originated from MapServer, using the following code

```
airwaysLayer.setSource(createAWYs('airways,navpoints'));
```

where `airwaysLayer` is of type `ol.layer.Image`.

Using now `handlePrintMap()` produces the following error

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27260385/475125) answer but in vain.

Comment: MapServer needs to have CORS enabled, or you need to run the request through a proxy instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was found in [this](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/38308/osm-tile-server-how-to-enable-cors) post.

I had to add `crossOrigin: null` in `createAWYs` function (code given below) as shown in [OL3 documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.ImageWMS.html).

```
function createAWYs(mapservquery) {
  var wmsSource = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?',
    params: {
      'SERVICE':'WMS',
      'map': 'C:/xampp/maps/airways.map',          
      'LAYERS': mapservquery,
      'VERSION':'1.3.0',
      'REQUEST':'GetMap',
      'FORMAT':"image/png"
    },
    serverType: 'mapserver', 
    ratio: 1,
    crossOrigin: null
  });
  return wmsSource;
}
```