# Cut Image In Grid And Flip It

Tags: jquery, html, css

Example image:

[image]

*Sorry, actually grid is not in correct size, just for example.

How can I made it cut based on grid and flip it? Actually what I want is after flip, it will show content like this:

[image]

How can I do it? I'm expect I don't need to cut all images, if can, just put that wallpaper, and it will cut automatically.

Comment: Here is an old question that will get you started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912917/cutting-an-image-into-pieces-through-javascript

Answer (score 5):

Using `background-position` is a very well-known way to divide some image into small pieces. From that technique you can totally solve your problem step by step. I've tried this code to demonstrate the techinque as well as solve your problem.

**HTML**:

```
<div class='canvas'></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.canvas {
  background:url('http://placekitten.com/500/300');
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
}
.cell {    
  float:left;    
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.cell > .front {            
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transition:all 1s;
}
.cell:not(.flipped) > .back {
  -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
.cell.flipped > .front {
  -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
.back {
  background:pink;
}
.cell > .back {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
  color:red;    
  left:0;
  top:0;    
  transition:all 1s;    
}
.cell > .back:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.cell > * {
  border: 1px solid orange;    
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
}
```

**JS**:

```
//get the canvas
var canvas = $('div.canvas');
var backgroundImage = canvas.css('background-image');
//remove the background from canvas
canvas.css('background-image','none');
//number of columns and rows
var col = 8;
var row = 4;
var colWidth = canvas.width() / col;
var rowHeight = canvas.height() / row;
//loop through the cells
for(var i = 0; i < row; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < col; j++){
    //append new cell to canvas
    var cell = $("<div class='cell flipped'><div class='back'>?</div><div class='front'></div></div>")
               .width(colWidth).height(rowHeight).appendTo(canvas);
    //set the background for the cell
    //note that calculate the em unit for more flexible
    //font-size
    cell.find('.front')
        .css('background',backgroundImage)
        .css('background-position', -(j * colWidth) + 'px ' + -(i * rowHeight) + 'px');
    //register click handler for the cell
    cell.click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('flipped')});
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: Please test the demo in webkit-based browsers, I've just added prefix for webkit-based browsers (for the `backface-visibility`, `transform`, ...). Also note that this code is not complete, it just helps you get started to fulfil your actual requirement.

A little explanation on the CSS, in fact you need 2 faces on a cell, the `.front` and `.back` face, the `.front` to render the image and the `.back` to render the text (after cell flipped). At flipped state, the `.front` should be rotated `180deg` around the `Y` axis (the vertical axis), however its `backface-visibility` should be set to `hidden`. In contradiction, `.back` should be rotated `180deg` around the Y axis in normal state.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/LdR29/)

**UPDATED**: Some browsers have not supported `backface-visibility` feature (such as ***Maxthon***), so you have another beautiful workaround by using `z-index` instead. In flipped state, the `.back` should have higher `z-index` (such as `1`) to cover the `.front`, while in normal state, it should have a zero `z-index` so that it's hidden behind the `.front`. Here is the **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LdR29/1/)** working on browsers which don't support `backface-visibility`)