# Converting a Cubemap into Equirectangular Panorama

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, unity-game-engine

I want to convert from cube map [figure1] into an equirectangular panorama [figure2].

Figure1
[image: Figure1]

Figure2
[image]

It is possible to go from Spherical to Cubic (by following: [Convert 2:1 equirectangular panorama to cube map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678510/convert-21-equirectangular-panorama-to-cube-map) ), but lost on how to reverse it.

Figure2 is to be rendered into a sphere using Unity.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming the input image is in the following cubemap format:

[image: Cubemap image]

The goal is to project the image to the equirectangular format like so:

[image: Equirectangular image]

The conversion algorithm is rather straightforward. 
In order to calculate the best **estimate** of the color at each pixel in the equirectangular image given a cubemap with 6 faces:

- Firstly, calculate polar coordinates that correspond to each pixel in
  the spherical image.
- Secondly, using the polar coordinates form a vector and determine on
  which face of the cubemap and which pixel of that face the vector
  lies; just like a raycast from the center of a cube would hit one of
  its sides and a specific point on that side.

Keep in mind that there are multiple methods to estimate the color of a pixel in the equirectangular image given a normalized coordinate (u,v) on a specific face of a cubemap. The most basic method, which is a very raw approximation and will be used in this answer for simplicity's sake, is to round the coordinates to a specific pixel and use that pixel. Other more advanced methods could calculate an average of a few neighbouring pixels.

The implementation of the algorithm will vary depending on the context. I did a quick implementation in Unity3D C# that shows how to implement the algorithm in a real world scenario. It runs on the CPU, there is a lot room for improvement but it is easy to understand.

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class CubemapConverter
{
    public static byte[] ConvertToEquirectangular(Texture2D sourceTexture, int outputWidth, int outputHeight)
    {
        Texture2D equiTexture = new Texture2D(outputWidth, outputHeight, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        float u, v; //Normalised texture coordinates, from 0 to 1, starting at lower left corner
        float phi, theta; //Polar coordinates
        int cubeFaceWidth, cubeFaceHeight;

        cubeFaceWidth = sourceTexture.width / 4; //4 horizontal faces
        cubeFaceHeight = sourceTexture.height / 3; //3 vertical faces


        for (int j = 0; j < equiTexture.height; j++)
        {
            //Rows start from the bottom
            v = 1 - ((float)j / equiTexture.height);
            theta = v * Mathf.PI;

            for (int i = 0; i < equiTexture.width; i++)
            {
                //Columns start from the left
                u = ((float)i / equiTexture.width);
                phi = u * 2 * Mathf.PI;

                float x, y, z; //Unit vector
                x = Mathf.Sin(phi) * Mathf.Sin(theta) * -1;
                y = Mathf.Cos(theta);
                z = Mathf.Cos(phi) * Mathf.Sin(theta) * -1;

                float xa, ya, za;
                float a;

                a = Mathf.Max(new float[3] { Mathf.Abs(x), Mathf.Abs(y), Mathf.Abs(z) });

                //Vector Parallel to the unit vector that lies on one of the cube faces
                xa = x / a;
                ya = y / a;
                za = z / a;

                Color color;
                int xPixel, yPixel;
                int xOffset, yOffset;

                if (xa == 1)
                {
                    //Right
                    xPixel = (int)((((za + 1f) / 2f) - 1f) * cubeFaceWidth);
                    xOffset = 2 * cubeFaceWidth; //Offset
                    yPixel = (int)((((ya + 1f) / 2f)) * cubeFaceHeight);
                    yOffset = cubeFaceHeight; //Offset
                }
                else if (xa == -1)
                {
                    //Left
                    xPixel = (int)((((za + 1f) / 2f)) * cubeFaceWidth);
                    xOffset = 0;
                    yPixel = (int)((((ya + 1f) / 2f)) * cubeFaceHeight);
                    yOffset = cubeFaceHeight;
                }
                else if (ya == 1)
                {
                    //Up
                    xPixel = (int)((((xa + 1f) / 2f)) * cubeFaceWidth);
                    xOffset = cubeFaceWidth;
                    yPixel = (int)((((za + 1f) / 2f) - 1f) * cubeFaceHeight);
                    yOffset = 2 * cubeFaceHeight;
                }
                else if (ya == -1)
                {
                    //Down
                    xPixel = (int)((((xa + 1f) / 2f)) * cubeFaceWidth);
                    xOffset = cubeFaceWidth;
                    yPixel = (int)((((za + 1f) / 2f)) * cubeFaceHeight);
                    yOffset = 0;
                }
                else if (za == 1)
                {
                    //Front
                    xPixel = (int)((((xa + 1f) / 2f)) * cubeFaceWidth);
                    xOffset = cubeFaceWidth;
                    yPixel = (int)((((ya + 1f) / 2f)) * cubeFaceHeight);
                    yOffset = cubeFaceHeight;
                }
                else if (za == -1)
                {
                    //Back
                    xPixel = (int)((((xa + 1f) / 2f) - 1f) * cubeFaceWidth);
                    xOffset = 3 * cubeFaceWidth;
                    yPixel = (int)((((ya + 1f) / 2f)) * cubeFaceHeight);
                    yOffset = cubeFaceHeight;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning("Unknown face, something went wrong");
                    xPixel = 0;
                    yPixel = 0;
                    xOffset = 0;
                    yOffset = 0;
                }

                xPixel = Mathf.Abs(xPixel);
                yPixel = Mathf.Abs(yPixel);

                xPixel += xOffset;
                yPixel += yOffset;

                color = sourceTexture.GetPixel(xPixel, yPixel);
                equiTexture.SetPixel(i, j, color);
            }
        }

        equiTexture.Apply();
        var bytes = equiTexture.EncodeToPNG();
        Object.DestroyImmediate(equiTexture);

        return bytes;
    }
}
```

In order to utilize the GPU I created a shader that does the same conversion. It is much faster than running the conversion pixel by pixel on the CPU but unfortunately Unity imposes resolution limitations on cubemaps so it's usefulness is limited in scenarios when high resolution input image is to be used.

```
Shader "Conversion/CubemapToEquirectangular" {
  Properties {
        _MainTex ("Cubemap (RGB)", CUBE) = "" {}
    }

    Subshader {
        Pass {
            ZTest Always Cull Off ZWrite Off
            Fog { Mode off }      

            CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
                //#pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_nicest
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                #define PI    3.141592653589793
                #define TWOPI 6.283185307179587

                struct v2f {
                    float4 pos : POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                samplerCUBE _MainTex;

                v2f vert( appdata_img v )
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                    o.uv = v.texcoord.xy * float2(TWOPI, PI);
                    return o;
                }

                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR 
                {
                    float theta = i.uv.y;
                    float phi = i.uv.x;
                    float3 unit = float3(0,0,0);

                    unit.x = sin(phi) * sin(theta) * -1;
                    unit.y = cos(theta) * -1;
                    unit.z = cos(phi) * sin(theta) * -1;

                    return texCUBE(_MainTex, unit);
                }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
    Fallback Off
}
```

The quality of the resulting images can be greatly improved by either employing a more sophisticated method to estimate the color of a pixel during the conversion or by post processing the resulting image (or both, actually). For example an image of bigger size could be generated to apply a blur filter and then downsample it to the desired size.

I created a simple Unity project with two editor wizards that show how to properly utilize either the C# code or the shader shown above. Get it here:
https://github.com/Mapiarz/CubemapToEquirectangular

Remember to set proper import settings in Unity for your input images:

- Point filtering
- Truecolor format
- Disable mipmaps
- Non Power of 2: None (only for 2DTextures)
- Enable Read/Write (only for 2DTextures)

Comment: If I wanted to rotate the cubemap before mapping it onto the sphere (which is then mapped on the 2D face), how would I do so?

Comment: @Bartosz - I've converted this code into c++ openCV, I'm having issue at this line `a = Mathf.Max(new float[3] { Mathf.Abs(x), Mathf.Abs(y), Mathf.Abs(z) });` - because a is returned as 0 when x,y,z values are below 1, which makes xa, xy and xz as undefined, due to divided by zero problem, am I missing something ?

my c++ line looks like this: `a = maximum(abs(x), abs(y), abs(z));` (I've added a maximum function of my own).

Comment: hi ! I've analyzed you're code for some time. 
Do you have any ideea of a solution for more than 6 faces ?
In you're case, you have 6 faces, each one for 1 axes ( x, y, z, -x, -y, -z)
In case of multiple faces/images, each image would have it's own "face", also it's own "axes". This was my ideea, by i couldn't continue from here.
Can you help me ?

Comment: This is a great answer

Comment: Thank you! What if one want to generate the spheremap using 6 seperate textures, each representing a side?

Comment: @McMidas Hey! Did you found a way to do it with 6 seperates textures? I know this is quite old but I was wondering :)

Answer (score 4):

[cube2sphere](https://github.com/Xyene/cube2sphere) automates the entire process. Example:

```
$ cube2sphere front.jpg back.jpg right.jpg left.jpg top.jpg bottom.jpg -r 2048 1024 -fTGA -ostitched
```

Answer (score 0):

Bartosz's answer works, but there is numerical instability in his code that is trigged when compiler optimization converts the unit vector division into multiplication by the inverse. The result of this operation may not be exactly 1.0, causing the IFs fail (it well known that floats don't like == after a math operation).

The fix for this issue is to change the IFs to compare with +/- a, instead.

```cpp
else if (xa == -1) // don't do this
else if (vx == -a) // do this
```

Also, as for optimization, `sin(theta)` and `cos(theta)` can be pre-calculated outside the inner loop.

Another issue is that this code does not do interpolation. I'd recommend to implement it in order to have better image quality. I used bicubic interpolation, except for the edges of the tiles. Worked well.