# OPENGL 6 Images CubeMap to equirectangular using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, opengl, panoramas, 360-panorama

I would like some help to make a conversion. I have 6 separate pictures, and I would like to put a spherical image in a picturebox.

I already researched in many places, but the only ones I found are in C ++ and others in Unity and JavaScript.

Here are some examples that I found but could not mount just in C # Windows Forms

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250742/converting-a-cubemap-into-equirectangular-panorama)

[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678510/convert-21-equirectangular-panorama-to-cube-map)

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627869/how-to-view-360-image-using-c-sharp) has been unanswered for a while. I'd say there probably isn't a good solution for WinForms.

Comment: only missing this in the system that is done in windows forms, one form controls another form. I do not know if you have as a web page to control another