# Tool for creating preview images from equirectangular Panoramas

Tags: panoramas, 360-panorama

I am looking for a tool or library that will allow me to generate a preview image for an equirectangular panoramic image. I am using the pannellum library [https://pannellum.org] to present panoramas, which works great. What I'd like to add, however, is a way to generate lightweight preview images to display on initial page load. I would like to have a small sized preview image that does not look warped. Does such a tool/library/script exist?

Thank you!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Some people like to convert panoramas to cube maps, which is a lot easier to google.

I've been looking at https://github.com/denivip/panorama, or also at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43469036/2471983 if you want a pure JavaScript approach (check out that entire question page for lots of info). Both of these will by default create all six cube faces; you can either edit them or just throw out the five extra faces.

Once you have this unprojected image, you can resize it using whatever utility you like.