# Create a screenshot server based with WebGL content

Tags: php, debian, webgl

I need to create a preview of an uploaded file.
Problem: The file will be a 360° panorama, and i use [pannellum](https://pannellum.org/) as display library.
So i installed [pageres](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres) on my debian server and after uploading i just exectute this PHP line:

```
exec("pageres https://myserver.com/preview.html?PicCode=$Code&Width=$Width&Height=$Height' {$Width}x$Height --crop --filename '$Code' > /dev/null &");
```

And it definitely works GREAT! I got a perfect screenshot. Unfortunately (and like expected) it's just the message that WebGL is not supported on "this device"... :(

I searched Stackoverflow, Googled around. Unfortunately no helpful idea.
So i would need a Guru (or just some1 who knows how to Google for the right solution) to help me out. Actually i need a 2-step-process for the customer (1st upload, 2nd click for creating a preview) and that's not really funny.

How could i enable pageres to render a simple 2D-canvas?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Pageres and Pannellum together, what if you instead got an offline utility that created a panorama preview for you? This question then becomes very similar to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077077/tool-for-creating-preview-images-from-equirectangular-panoramas). There's lots of info to be had also in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678510/convert-21-equirectangular-panorama-to-cube-map).

In short, I recommend looking at, for example, this command-line utility: https://github.com/denivip/panorama

Comment: Well, i know about the tools you mentioned.
But i have as source an equirectangular panorama and want to create a preview with a preset pitch / yaw / hfov.
And this won't work with the "how to create a cubemap" things, you mentioned.
I will try an approach to modify pannellum in a way that i'll get the RGB pixel matrix and convert it into an image. This looks actually like the only way to go.