# Projecting equirectangular image onto a plane

Tags: image-processing, projection

Given a 3D cuboid and an equirectangular image, I want to map the image onto the inside of a cuboid (only the side faces, not top or bottom). To do this I want to create textures for each face of the cuboid from the equirectangular image.

The image is from a room and I have labelled the top and bottom corners in the panorama which correspond to corners of my cuboid. The image is not from the inside of the room and I wish to create a texture for each face.

I tried solution given here: [Convert 2:1 equirectangular panorama to cube map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678510/convert-21-equirectangular-panorama-to-cube-map/29681646#29681646)

But that is for a cube, where each texture is the same size. I have looked at other resources but I feel I need another explanation such that I can fully understand how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Im quite sure that changing the one of a cube to a rectangle is quite easy if you try

Comment: I have been trying and experiencing some difficulty. I have managed to get it to work in the horizontal direction, I am just having issue in the vertical. It also assumes the centre of the cube is the centre of the image. The camera was not exactly half the height of the walls. 

I also do not really understand what the sides ak and an really correspond to. There are a few places where they use the same value for both directions since it is a cube.

Comment: Then show what you tried!