# Does threejs not divide by depth?

Tags: three.js, projection, projection-matrix, homogenous-transformation

Question: *Shouldn't threejs set the `w` value of vertices equal to their depth?*

When projecting objects onto a screen, objects that are far away from the focal point get projected further towards the center of the screen. In [projective coordinates](https://www.tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/explaining-homogenous-coordinates-and-projective-geometry/) this effect is achieved by dividing a point's (`x, y, z`)-coordinates by its distance from the focal point, `w`.  I've been playing around with `threejs`'s projection matrix and it seems to me that threejs doesn't do that.

Consider the following scene:

```js
// src/main.ts
import { AmbientLight, BoxGeometry, DirectionalLight, Mesh,
MeshPhongMaterial, PerspectiveCamera, Scene, WebGLRenderer } from "three";

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;

const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({
  alpha: false,
  antialias: false,
  canvas: canvas,
  depth: true
});

const scene = new Scene();

const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(45, canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.01, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);

const light = new DirectionalLight();
light.position.set(-1, 0, 3);
scene.add(light);
const light2 = new AmbientLight();
scene.add(light2);

const cube = new Mesh(new BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1, 1), new MeshPhongMaterial({ color: `rgb(0, 125, 125)` }));
scene.add(cube);
cube.position.set(3.42, 3.42, 0);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
      <canvas id="canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code yields the following image:
[image: box in threejs-scene in far-top-right undistorted]

Note how the edges of the turquoise box appear exactly parallel to the edges of the canvas. But the front-top-right vertex is further away from my eye than the front-bottom-left vertex. Shouldn't the top-right vertex be slightly distorted towards the center?

I understand that WebGL automatically divides vertices by their `w` coordinate in the [vertex-post-processing-phase](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview). Shouldn't threejs have used the depth to set `w` so that this distortion-effect is achieved?

What I imagine is something like this:

```js
import { AmbientLight, BoxGeometry, Mesh, MeshBasicMaterial, PerspectiveCamera,
  Scene, ShaderMaterial, SpotLight, TextureLoader, Vector3, WebGLRenderer } from "three";


const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;

const loader = new TextureLoader();
const texture = await loader.loadAsync('bricks.jpg');

const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({
  alpha: false,
  antialias: true,
  canvas: canvas,
  depth: true
});

const scene = new Scene();

const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(45, canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.01, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 0, -1);
camera.lookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));

const light = new SpotLight();
light.position.set(-1, 0, -1);
scene.add(light);
const light2 = new AmbientLight();
scene.add(light2);

const box = new Mesh(new BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1, 50, 50, 50), new MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: texture
}));
scene.add(box);
box.position.set(-0.6, 0, 1);

const box2 = new Mesh(new BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1, 50, 50, 50), new ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: { 
    tTexture: {value: texture } 
  },
  vertexShader: `
    varying vec2 vUv;
    void main() {
      vUv = uv;
      vec4 clipSpacePos = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
      clipSpacePos.w = length(clipSpacePos.xyz);
      gl_Position = clipSpacePos;
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    varying vec2 vUv;
    uniform sampler2D tTexture;
    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(tTexture, vUv);
    }
  `,
}));
scene.add(box2);
box2.position.set(0.6, 0, 1);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Which gives the following output:
[image: two blocks with brick-texture, one has strong barrel distortion]

Note how the left block displays strong distortion towards the edges.

Comment: I'm now learning that this kind of effect is known as [barrel distortion](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/barrel-distortion). It appears that this is an unwanted side-effect of camera-lenses. Yet I'm still not certain if our eyes don't sense some amount of barrel distortion naturally.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand my mistake now.

My approach was setting `w = distance` for each vertex instead of `w = z` (which is - simplified - what the standard projection matrix does).

This has the GPU normalize all points by their distance from the focal point instead of by their distance from a straight plane. In other words: this has the GPU project all vertices onto a *sphere* around me instead of onto a plane in front of me.

I think the same difference becomes clearer when looking at the [difference between a `cube-map` and an `equirectangular-map`](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Aakanksha-Rana/publication/335258068/figure/fig1/AS:793818739769345@1566272544478/Visual-representation-of-equirectangular-and-cubemap-projections-for-the-captured-360.png)(image).

Please do correct me if I'm wrong, but I guess that an equirectangular projection is obtained by projecting onto a curved surface.

Also, [this stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678510/convert-21-equirectangular-panorama-to-cube-map) does indicate that an equirectangular map needs to be *undistorted* - that is, straightened - before it can be used as a cube-map. (Side-note: kudos for some very illustrative images there!)

In other words: If we're going with the "project on a plane" metaphor, then three's default perspective-projection matrix, which has points normalized by `z`, is what we want. If we're going for the "project on a sphere" metaphor, we indeed want to normalize by distance. Since my monitor is a flat plane, the divide-by-z strategy is the appropriate thing to do.

(Of course, corrections and additions are *very* welcome!)

Comment: I think the following example illustrates the issue.

You're looking straight at a long, not very high, brick-wall.
Notice how the far away parts of the wall seem to get smaller and smaller.
Still when projecting that wall onto a screen parallel to the wall in front of you, the projection will have the wall's edges align with the screen's edges perfectly.

Your eyes will *still* see the wall's edges taper off towards the edges, however. The reason is because the rays from the screen get projected onto the *sphere* of your eyeballs.