How do I convert a 300-degree equirectangular panoramic image to cube faces?
A 300-degree equirectangular panoramic image I want to convert into cube faces using OpenCV in Python. I found code for 360-degree images. How do I modify it to handle a 300-degree image?
import cv2
import numpy as np


def equirectangular_to_cube(img, cube_size):
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    #
    # Create cube map faces
    cube_faces = np.zeros((cube_size, cube_size * 6, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    #
    # Calculate the size of each cube face
    face_size = cube_size
    #
    # Define the mapping coordinates for 360 degrees
    x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num=w, dtype=np.float32)
    y = np.linspace(np.pi / 2, -np.pi / 2, num=h, dtype=np.float32)
    #
    # Create grid of coordinates
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    #
    # Calculate 3D coordinates
    z = np.cos(yy) * np.cos(xx)
    x = np.cos(yy) * np.sin(xx)
    y = np.sin(yy)
    #
    # Normalize coordinates
    norm = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
    x /= norm
    y /= norm
    z /= norm
    #
    # Map coordinates to cube faces
    front_mask = (z >= np.abs(x)) & (z >= np.abs(y))
    right_mask = (x >= np.abs(y)) & (x >= np.abs(z))
    back_mask = (z <= -np.abs(x)) & (z <= -np.abs(y))
    left_mask = (x <= -np.abs(y)) & (x <= -np.abs(z))
    top_mask = (y >= np.abs(x)) & (y >= np.abs(z))
    bottom_mask = (y <= -np.abs(x)) & (y <= -np.abs(z))
    #
    # Interpolate and assign pixel values to cube faces
    for i in range(cube_size):
        for j in range(cube_size):
            # Front face
            u = (0.5 + 0.5 * x[front_mask] / z[front_mask]) * (w - 1)
            v = (0.5 + 0.5 * y[front_mask] / z[front_mask]) * (h - 1)
            cube_faces[i, j] = cv2.remap(img, u.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.float32), v.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.float32), cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
            #
            # Right face
            u = (0.5 + 0.5 * z[right_mask] / x[right_mask]) * (w - 1)
            v = (0.5 + 0.5 * y[right_mask] / x[right_mask]) * (h - 1)
            cube_faces[i, j + cube_size] = cv2.remap(img, u.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.float32), v.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.float32), cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
            #
            # Back face
            u = (0.5 - 0.5 * x[back_mask] / z[back_mask]) * (w - 1)
            v = (0.5 + 0.5 * y[back_mask] / z[back_mask]) * (h - 1)
            cube_faces[i, j + cube_size*2] = cv2.remap(img, u.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.float32), v.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.float32), cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
            #
            # Left face
            u = (0.5 - 0.5 * z[left_mask] / x[left_mask]) * (w - 1)
            v = (0.5 + 0.5 * y[left_mask] / x[left_mask]) * (h - 1)
            cube_faces[i, j + cube_size*3] = cv2.remap(img, u.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.float32), v.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.float32), cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
            #
            # Top face
            u = (0.5 + 0.5 * x[top_mask] / y[top_mask]) * (w - 1)
            v = (0.5 - 0.5 * z[top_mask] / y[top_mask]) * (h - 1)
            cube_faces[i, j + cube_size*4] = cv2.remap(img, u.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.float32), v.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.float32), cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
            #
            # Bottom face
            u = (0.5 + 0.5 * x[bottom_mask] / y[bottom_mask]) * (w - 1)
            v = (0.5 + 0.5 * z[bottom_mask] / y[bottom_mask]) * (h - 1)
            cube_faces[i, j + cube_size*5] = cv2.remap(img, u.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.float32), v.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.float32), cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    #
    return cube_faces


# Usage example
image_path = 'path/to/300_degree_image.jpg'
cube_size = 512
img = cv2.imread(image_path)
cube_faces = equirectangular_to_cube(img, cube_size)

# Save the cube faces as separate images
front = cube_faces[:, :cube_size]
right = cube_faces[:, cube_size:cube_size*2]
back = cube_faces[:, cube_size*2:cube_size*3]
left = cube_faces[:, cube_size*3:cube_size*4]
top = cube_faces[:, cube_size*4:cube_size*5]
bottom = cube_faces[:, cube_size*5:]

cv2.imwrite("front.jpg", front)
cv2.imwrite("right.jpg", right)
cv2.imwrite("back.jpg", back)
cv2.imwrite("left.jpg", left)
cv2.imwrite("top.jpg", top)
cv2.imwrite("bottom.jpg", bottom)

It defines mapping coordinates for a 360-degree image using np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num=w, dtype=np.float32). How do I modify it to account for the reduced field of view?
Image:

What I've tried:
# convert using an inverse transformation
def convertBack(imgIn,imgOut):
    inSize = imgIn.size
    outSize = imgOut.size
    inPix = imgIn.load()
    outPix = imgOut.load()
    #
    extendedSize = [0,0]
    extendedSize[0] = int(360/300 * inSize[0])
    extendedSize[1] = inSize[1]
    edge = int(extendedSize[0]/4)   # theoretical length of each edge
    #
    for i in range(outSize[0]):
        face = int(i/edge) # 0 - back, 1 - left 2 - front, 3 - right
        if face==2:
            rng = range(0,edge*3)
        else:
            rng = range(edge,edge*2)
        #
        for j in rng:
            if j<edge:
                face2 = 4 # top
            elif j>=2*edge:
                face2 = 5 # bottom
            else:
                face2 = face
            #
            (x,y,z) = outImgToXYZ(i,j,face2,edge)
            theta = atan2(y,x) # range -pi to pi
            r = hypot(x,y)
            phi = atan2(z,r) # range -pi/2 to pi/2
            # source img coords
            uf = ( 2.0*edge*(theta + pi)/pi )
            vf = ( 2.0*edge * (pi/2 - phi)/pi)

            if uf < inSize[0]:
                # Use bilinear interpolation between the four surrounding pixels
                ui = floor(uf)  # coord of pixel to bottom left
                vi = floor(vf)
                u2 = clip(ui+1, 0, inSize[0]-1) # Clip u2 to stay within the valid range
                v2 = clip(vi+1, 0, inSize[1]-1) # Clip v2 to stay within the valid range
                mu = uf-ui      # fraction of way across pixel
                nu = vf-vi
                # Pixel values of four corners
                A = inPix[ui,vi]
                B = inPix[u2,vi]
                C = inPix[ui,v2]
                D = inPix[u2,v2]
                # interpolate
                (r,g,b) = (
                    A[0]*(1-mu)*(1-nu) + B[0]*(mu)*(1-nu) + C[0]*(1-mu)*nu+D[0]*mu*nu,
                    A[1]*(1-mu)*(1-nu) + B[1]*(mu)*(1-nu) + C[1]*(1-mu)*nu+D[1]*mu*nu,
                    A[2]*(1-mu)*(1-nu) + B[2]*(mu)*(1-nu) + C[2]*(1-mu)*nu+D[2]*mu*nu )
            else:
                (r,g,b) = (0,0,0)
            #
            outPix[i,j] = (int(round(r)),int(round(g)),int(round(b)))

This is the change:
extendedSize = [0,0]
extendedSize[0] = int(360/300 * inSize[0])
extendedSize[1] = inSize[1]
edge = int(extendedSize[0]/4)   # theoretical length of each edge

Update:
I got it partially working. Any feedback would be very helpful.
I included my updated code below

# convert using an inverse transformation
def convertBack(imgIn,imgOut):
    inSize = imgIn.size
    outSize = imgOut.size
    inPix = imgIn.load()
    outPix = imgOut.load()
    extendedSize = imgIn.size
    extendedSize = (int(360/300 * inSize[0]), inSize[1])
    edge = extendedSize[0]/4   # theoretical length of edge
    # edge = inSize[0]/4   # the length of each edge in pixels
    for i in range(outSize[0]):
        # print(i)
        face = int(i/edge) # 0 - back, 1 - left 2 - front, 3 - right
        if face==2:
            rng = range(0, int(edge*3))
        else:
            rng = range(int(edge), int(edge*2))
        # 
        for j in rng:
            if j<edge:
                face2 = 4 # top
            elif j>=2*edge:
                face2 = 5 # bottom
            else:
                face2 = face
            # 
            (x,y,z) = outImgToXYZ(i,j,face2,edge)
            theta = atan2(y,x) # range -pi to pi
            r = hypot(x,y)
            phi = atan2(z,r) # range -pi/2 to pi/2
            # source img coords
            uf = ( 2.0*edge*(theta + pi)/pi )
            vf = ( 2.0*edge * (pi/2 - phi)/pi)
            # 
            if uf < inSize[0] :
                # Use bilinear interpolation between the four surrounding pixels
                ui = floor(uf)  # coord of pixel to bottom left
                vi = floor(vf)
                u2 = ui+1       # coords of pixel to top right
                v2 = vi+1
                mu = uf-ui      # fraction of way across pixel
                nu = vf-vi
                # 
                # Clip coordinates to stay within the valid range
                ui = max(0, min(ui, extendedSize[0]-1))
                u2 = max(0, min(u2, extendedSize[0]-1))
                vi = max(0, min(vi, extendedSize[1]-1))
                v2 = max(0, min(v2, extendedSize[1]-1))
                # # 
                # # Pixel values of four corners
                A = inPix[ui % inSize[0],clip(vi,0,inSize[1]-1)]
                B = inPix[u2 % inSize[0],clip(vi,0,inSize[1]-1)]
                C = inPix[ui % inSize[0],clip(v2,0,inSize[1]-1)]
                D = inPix[u2 % inSize[0],clip(v2,0,inSize[1]-1)]
                # interpolate
                (r,g,b) = (
                    A[0]*(1-mu)*(1-nu) + B[0]*(mu)*(1-nu) + C[0]*(1-mu)*nu+D[0]*mu*nu,
                    A[1]*(1-mu)*(1-nu) + B[1]*(mu)*(1-nu) + C[1]*(1-mu)*nu+D[1]*mu*nu,
                    A[2]*(1-mu)*(1-nu) + B[2]*(mu)*(1-nu) + C[2]*(1-mu)*nu+D[2]*mu*nu )
                # 
                # (r,g,b) = (0,0,0) 
            else:
                (r,g,b) = (0,0,0)
            # 
            # Clip the coordinates to stay within the output image dimensions
            i_clipped = max(0, min(i, outSize[0]-1))
            j_clipped = max(0, min(j, outSize[1]-1))
            outPix[i_clipped,j_clipped] = (int(round(r)),int(round(g)),int(round(b)))



context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78779377/i-am-trying-to-cubemap-an-image-but-am-running-into-some-issues?noredirect=1#comment138903554_78779377 by Snhorq

You could perhaps pad your image and resize to 2:1 aspect ratio so that it is equivalently 360 degrees?

While [edit]ing, remove all the metacommentary as well. Having asked 240 question over 5 years, you ought to know that doesn't belong in a question post. | How do you intend to handle the missing 1/6th of the view? (As in, what do you expect the result to look like in that area)

I'm hoping to just have an undistorted version of my 300 degree image. I was thinking of taking the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678510/convert-21-equirectangular-panorama-to-cube-map/29681646#29681646 and applying it to a 300 degree image instead

If you don't have a full 360 deg input, then the sides of the result would not be squares and you would not have a full cube. I don't know if this helps or perhaps you have seen and are using it: see the code at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_mapping.

the sides would be squares, but some of them would have incomplete coverage. -- the last picture in your question looks mostly reasonable, but shifted and even cropped, so I'd suggest considering (phase) shifts in the mapping calculations.

first you should confirm your understanding of the involved projections, which are equirect, polar/spherical, and cubemap (six times a simple projective/pinhole model). then you should confirm your understanding of the calculations to map from one projection to the other. I mentioned polar/spherical because that is an intermediate step you'll absolutely WANT to take, if you want these equations to make any kind of sense.

I looked at ptgui this morning and it was able to do equi rectangle conversions for each of the sections. Do you think I could just split the image into tiles and run equirectangle projects on each? I really want to get this finished

I think the problem comes from the edge variable. It should be computed from the outSize instead of the inSize. I would use
edge = outSize[0]/4   # theoretical length of edge

Once you have fixed that, the source coordinates uf and vf that appear a few lines later cannot rely any longer on the edge variable, and must be changed to:
# source img coords
uf = extendedSize[0] * (theta + pi) / (2 * pi)
vf = extendedSize[1] * (pi / 2 - phi) / pi

Here is the result with those changes:

The skyline is very distorted, as well as road on the bottom cube face. I guess your picture is closer to 150 degree instead of 180 vertically (and assume the 30 missing degrees are at the bottom).
By changing extendedSize to
extendedSize = (int(360/300 * inSize[0]), int(180/150 * inSize[1]))

and the if statement
if uf < inSize[0] and vf < inSize[1]:

I get

So the complete code becomes
# convert using an inverse transformation
def convertBack(imgIn,imgOut):
    inSize = imgIn.size
    outSize = imgOut.size
    inPix = imgIn.load()
    outPix = imgOut.load()
    extendedSize = imgIn.size
    extendedSize = (int(360/300 * inSize[0]), int(180/150 * inSize[1]))
    edge = outSize[0]/4   # theoretical length of edge
    # edge = inSize[0]/4   # the length of each edge in pixels
    for i in range(outSize[0]):
        # print(i)
        face = int(i/edge) # 0 - back, 1 - left 2 - front, 3 - right
        if face==2:
            rng = range(0, int(edge*3))
        else:
            rng = range(int(edge), int(edge*2))
        # 
        for j in rng:
            if j<edge:
                face2 = 4 # top
            elif j>=2*edge:
                face2 = 5 # bottom
            else:
                face2 = face
            # 
            (x,y,z) = outImgToXYZ(i,j,face2,edge)
            theta = atan2(y,x) # range -pi to pi
            r = hypot(x,y)
            phi = atan2(z,r) # range -pi/2 to pi/2
            # source img coords
            uf = extendedSize[0] * (theta + pi) / (2 * pi)
            vf = extendedSize[1] * (pi/2 - phi) / pi
            # 
            if uf < inSize[0] and vf < inSize[1] :
                # Use bilinear interpolation between the four surrounding pixels
                ui = floor(uf)  # coord of pixel to bottom left
                vi = floor(vf)
                u2 = ui+1       # coords of pixel to top right
                v2 = vi+1
                mu = uf-ui      # fraction of way across pixel
                nu = vf-vi
                # 
                # Clip coordinates to stay within the valid range
                ui = max(0, min(ui, extendedSize[0]-1))
                u2 = max(0, min(u2, extendedSize[0]-1))
                vi = max(0, min(vi, extendedSize[1]-1))
                v2 = max(0, min(v2, extendedSize[1]-1))
                # # 
                # # Pixel values of four corners
                A = inPix[ui % inSize[0],clip(vi,0,inSize[1]-1)]
                B = inPix[u2 % inSize[0],clip(vi,0,inSize[1]-1)]
                C = inPix[ui % inSize[0],clip(v2,0,inSize[1]-1)]
                D = inPix[u2 % inSize[0],clip(v2,0,inSize[1]-1)]
                # interpolate
                (r,g,b) = (
                    A[0]*(1-mu)*(1-nu) + B[0]*(mu)*(1-nu) + C[0]*(1-mu)*nu+D[0]*mu*nu,
                    A[1]*(1-mu)*(1-nu) + B[1]*(mu)*(1-nu) + C[1]*(1-mu)*nu+D[1]*mu*nu,
                    A[2]*(1-mu)*(1-nu) + B[2]*(mu)*(1-nu) + C[2]*(1-mu)*nu+D[2]*mu*nu )
                # 
                # (r,g,b) = (0,0,0) 
            else:
                (r,g,b) = (0,0,0)
            # 
            # Clip the coordinates to stay within the output image dimensions
            i_clipped = max(0, min(i, outSize[0]-1))
            j_clipped = max(0, min(j, outSize[1]-1))
            outPix[i_clipped,j_clipped] = (int(round(r)),int(round(g)),int(round(b)))


Show your result!

this amount of trial and error goes to show that OP has got data without an adequate description (cropped in unknown ways)
